# error on copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

My header files looks this :

```
class A
{
public:

    A();

    A(A const & other);

private:

class B
{
    public:
    B * child;

    int x;
    int y;

    void copy( B * other);
};

B * root;

void copy( B * other);

};
```

While my cpp files is:

```
A::A()
{
root = NULL;
}

A::A(A const & other)
{
if (other.root == NULL)
{
    root = NULL;
    return;
}

copy(other.root);
}

void A::copy( B * other)
{
if (other == NULL)
    return;

this->x = other->x;
this->y = other->y;

this->child->copy(other->child);
}
```

However, when I compile my code I get the error - 'class A has no member named x'

I am guessing that this is because 'x' is a member of class B which is private. Is it possible to make a copy constructor without changing the structure of the header file.

Comment: in `void A::copy(B* other)`, `this->x` means `A::x` and A has no x or y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing that this is because 'x' is a member of class B which is
>   private.

No, it's because, as the error says, "class A has no member named x".  Class `B` does.  In the function `A::copy`, `this` is a pointer to an `A` object, but you are trying to access non-existent members `x` and `y` through it.  Perhaps you meant this:

```
this->root->x = other->x;
this->root->y = other->y;
```

Comment: I have edited my code above to include a definition of 'copy' inside the B class with the exact same signature. Will this have any implications that I should be concerned about? I did it so that I am allowed to do `this->child->copy(other->child);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to distinguish between fields which belong to `A` and fields belonging to `B`.  The right way to write A's copy constructor seems to be:

```
void A::copy( B *other )
{
    this.root = other;
}
```

Writing a copy constructor for B is a whole different matter, but I'm not sure it's even relevant for this example.